# Cannot use external libraries for google app engine java project

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I have an Eclipse with Google App Engine Plugin and Google App Engine SDK 1.3.0 installed on.
I have created a new web project with Google App Engine SDK 1.3.0.
Now, I want to add a library for some advanced JSTL syntax in jsp file, it's is EL-functors (http://el-functors.sourceforge.net).
In order for EL-functors to pickup its advanced syntax in jsp file and compile them to standard jsp syntax, I must add some listener to the web.xml:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>beanface.el.functor.InstallFunctorListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Also, I have added standar.jar, jstl.jar, el-functors-1.0.3.jar to my build path.
However, when I kick off web server (using Debug As>Web Project), in the console log, I see this error message:

```
Initializing AppEngine server
Feb 5, 2010 7:22:45 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Could not instantiate listener beanface.el.functor.InstallFunctorListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: beanface.el.functor.InstallFunctorListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at ........
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:421)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1035)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:783)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:275)
```

I guess there should be some causes lead to the library is not loaded.
When I come to war/WEB-INF/lib, I cannot see standard.jar, jstl.jar and el-functors.1.0.3.jar overthere; only google app engine jars being deployed.

What is the problem there, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to copy the required jar(s) to the /WEB-INF/lib folder manually.

I faced a similar issue while starting to build with app-engine. After some research, I came to the conclusion that it is the only way to get it working.

Would love to know if I am wrong :)

Comment: Yes this works. But really: is it the *ONLY* way to get it working? No Eclipse-style build path management? war/WEB-INF/lib is *soooo* primitive!

Comment: This works for me too, but i'd like to know the reason why we have to put the jar under WEB-INF/lib even if we already has the class file in classpath? maybe the gwt dev mode just honor the class/jar in WEB-INF?

Comment: I think the reason why it has to be manually put inside `war/WEB-INF/lib` is that the entire Eclipse project is in your local machine. When you reference a jar file, you're basically pointing to a location somewhere in your computer. However, Google hosts the app using its own servers so there needs to be a copy of those jars on their side.

Comment: I can see that this might be necessary for deploying, but for dev-mode? Really? So, if I'm developing some parts of my app in a separate java project, I have to constantly go through the export process just for testing? Ouch... Uber-Ouch!

Comment: It would be uglier if it worked locally and didn't work in production.  At least seeing the error in dev mode will save you from thinking it will work when it won't.  Determinism++

Answer (score 5):

There is a user-friendly alternative to manual coping of jars - quick fix

Go to Markers View, find appropriate warning (The following classpath entry "...), select "quick fix" from the context menu and click on "copy .. to /WEB-INF/lib and update classpath to reference this jar"

Answer (score 1):

I am using App Wrench tool to automatically copy jars into /WEB-INF/lib directory. Works only if you do not have any @Entity marked classes in that jar.