# iText working Google App engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, itext

I'm trying create pdf in java with google app engine but it doesn't work yet:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GuestbookServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("application/pdf");
            try {
                Document document = new Document();
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("HelloWorld.pdf"));
                document.open();
                document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
                document.close();
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /guestbook. Reason:

    com/itextpdf/text/DocumentException
Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/DocumentException
```

I have read the incompatibility with java.awt and java.nio with google appengine. But I don't know how to do it. Is there any special version of itext to google app engine? Or do you know any clue that can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a GAE version of iText. See http://lowagie.com/iPadSchools to watch a demo. The GAE port is distributed by iText Software. There's no link to get it online.

Comment: It means that it can only be obtained on request by filling out the sales form on itextpdf.com.

Comment: Hello again! I filled out the sale form and they said me that I can test it download here: http://itextpdf.com/download.php a normal version because I can't buy a license without prove that iText has the right solution with GAE. Can I do working it?

Comment: Did you ask for a GAE trial-version?

Comment: Good morning Bruno, I try run the application with the specific library and I have the same exception. Have I to configure something else? I added the library to the project and that is it all. Do you know why I have this exception?

Comment: It works for us. See http://itextpdf.com/summit.php#talk2 You have to integrate iText into your APK the same way you would integrate any other library. After adding the jar to your project, your APK should be bigger. See http://stefan.fenz.at/creating-pdfs-on-android-an-evaluation/ for a comparison of different products. iText results in the highest application file size, but is much faster than other products.

Comment: Oops, I thought you were talking about Android. Now I see this is a GAE question. However: the answer remains the same. If you get a NoClassDefFound error, you've made a configuration error that is unrelated to iText.

Comment: Three possible reasons (ordered from most probable to least probable): 1. you don't have the iText GAE jar on the server. 2. you have more than 1 iText GAE jar on the server and this causes ambiguity. 3. there's a clash between different Java versions.

Comment: Configuration error? It has to be something related with adding the library because if I put other code without using iTex it works. I add library in java build path-> add external jars. Some else? And thank you for your help!

Comment: I've found the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205648/cannot-use-external-libraries-for-google-app-engine-java-project

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Happy to hear the problem is solved!

Answer (score 1):

```
package mx.gob.campeche.sit.web.reportes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import mx.gob.campeche.sit.doc.recibo_oficial.ReciboOficial;
@WebServlet("/reciboOficial")
public class ReporteReciboOficialServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    ReciboOficial reciboOficial;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpServletRequestWrapper srw = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request);
        String folio = "";

         if (request.getParameterMap().containsKey("folio")) {
                folio = request.getParameter("folio");
                System.out.println("contenido" + folio);
            }else
         if (request.getParameterMap().containsKey("numero")) {
                folio = request.getParameter("numero");
                System.out.println("contenido" + folio);
            }else{
                throw new ServletException("No ingreso parametro");
            }


        byte[] pdfData = reciboOficial.crearReciboOFicialCajas(folio,  srw.getRealPath(""));

        response.setContentType("application/pdf"); 
        response.reset();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition",  "inline; filename=\"" +"samplePDF2.pdf" +"\"");

        OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        output.write(pdfData);
        output.close();

    }
this is small example, this help
```