# iText in android priducing Could not find class

Tags: android, itext

```
10-02 05:36:39.589: E/dalvikvm(2570): Could not find class 'org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSEnvelopedData', 
referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDecryptedDocObj
```

The logcat shows this kind of error, I've been googling around and still can't find the solution.

here is the source code:

> MainActivity.java

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            GenerarPDF();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
        public void GenerarPDF()throws Exception{
            Document document = new Document();
            String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Hello.pdf";
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(file));
            document.open();
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Hello PDF");
            document.add(p);
            document.close();
        } 
}
```

here is my manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.samplepdf"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

can anyone point out a solution to this problem?

Comment: In what folder you located your itext libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're not using the offical Android port of iText. The official port doesn't use BouncyCastle. It uses SpongyCastle to avoid clashes with the old BouncyCastle version that is shipped with Android. Use the official port and the problem will disappear.

Comment: do you have any instruction on how to do that?

Comment: Go to the iText web site and ask for the GAE trial version (the same version can be used for Android): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580535/itext-working-google-app-engine/12580631#12580631